# "git describe" ignores a tag

Tags: git, git-tag, git-describe

In the following lines:

```
$ git tag -n1
v1.8        Tagged the day before yesterday
v1.9        Tagged yesterday
v2.0        Tagged today
$ git describe
v1.9-500-ga6a8c67
$
```

Can anyone explain why the v2.0 tag is not used by "git describe", and how to fix this? The v2.0 tag is already pushed, so I am guessing that I can't just delete and re-add it.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851344/git-describe-fails-to-return-most-recent-annotated-tag

Comment: I only did: git merge master, after that all have worked as a charm!!

Comment: For me, issue was a squashed commit. Tags remain even after commits are squashed

Answer (score 117, accepted):

[`git describe`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html) uses only annotated tags by default. Specify the `--tags` option to make it use lightweight tags as well.

Make sure you've checked out the correct commit (`git rev-parse HEAD`). Annotated tags are created with `git tag -a`. If you do `git show <tagname>` and you see the commit only, it's a lightweight tag; if you see an additional tag message, it's an annotated tag.

Comment: "git describe --tags" produces the same output as above.

Comment: you can also try `--all` to make it use all refs. is HEAD described by the tag? (just to make sure)

Comment: "git describe --all" prints "heads/master". The v2.0 tag is applied on the master branch. (I suppose that means it describes HEAD?)

Comment: `HEAD` is the currently checked out commit.

Comment: Ah, yes, HEAD is currently checked out. How to I tell whether a tag is annotated? "git tag" does not seem to have an option to show this.

Comment: make sure you've checked out the correct commit (`git rev-parse HEAD`) – also make sure you use the latest version of git. annotated tags are created with `git tag -a`. if you do `git show <tagname>` and you see the commit, it's a lightweight tag, if you see a tag message it's an annotated tag.

Comment: Ah-ha. "git show v1.9" prints the tag and the commit, while "git show v2.0" prints the commit only. Using `git tag -fa -m "Release 2.0" v2.0 785b92df5` fixed it. Thanks! (If you edit the original posting I can mark your answer.)

Answer (score 31):

When this happened to us, it was a case of two tags applied for the same commit. You can find if this is the case by running

```
# git log --oneline --decorate=short
deba4b4 (tag: v1.1.0.20.0, tag: v1.1.0.19.0) 001 New buildnumber
```

Here there are two tags, one for version 19 and other for 20. 20 was tagged after 19, but for the same commit. In this case describe returned

```
# git describe --tags
v1.1.0.19.0
```

I don't know why it did this, but this is how it seems to work with duplicate tags.

Another case where this might happen is if you have a tag that is more "near" to you in a branch. That case has been explained in [this blog post](http://www.xerxesb.com/2010/git-describe-and-the-tale-of-the-wrong-commits/).

Comment: I am having a similar issue, so I figured the best way would be to prevent creating duplicate annotated tags. Do you know how I could achieve that?

Comment: @jbucaran I guess you'd need to run a check and then tag or not tag based on that. that'd probably be topic for another question

Answer (score 26):

The issue is `git tag` shows *all* tags in all branches while `git describe` only uses tags on commits which are available in the current *branch*.

Here is an example (the reason why I came here actually):

```
 $ git tag | tail -n3
v0.4.0
v0.4.1
v0.4.2
```

It shows the latest tag available is `v0.4.2`, but this is my output of `git describe`:

```
 $ git describe --tags
v0.4.0-2-acd334c
```

I'm on develop branch. When I dig into the log, I see indeed the most recent tags are not available on the current branch:

```
 $ git log --oneline --decorate=short | grep 'tag\:' | head -n3
acd334c (tag: v0.4.0) Merge pull request #1061
988fe5e (tag: v0.3.6) Merge pull request #859
5f97274 (tag: v0.3.5) Merge pull request #646
```

So in my case, the developers decided to create a new *release* branch exclusively for tagging releases which results that the develop branch is not up to date with the tags anymore.

Hope that helps and thanks @eis for the idea with checking the logs.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely from your example, `v1.9` is a tag from merge commit.

It is expected git behavior by default and you can read more about it here: 
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/commit/?id=80dbae03

To ignore merge tags when looking for most recent on the current branch you can use `--first-parent` option.

```
git describe --tags --first-parent --abbrev=0
```

**--first-parent**

Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. This is useful when you wish to not match tags on branches merged in the history of the target commit.

Ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe