# Git describe fails to return most recent annotated tag

Tags: git, shell, unit-testing, git-tag

I wrote a function that uses `git` annotated tags to create new releases and/or bump semver style version numbers for my project.

I am in the process of adding unit tests and noticed that `git describe --abbrev=0` fails to retrieve the most recent tag, *only* when several `git tag -a <tag> -m <msg>` are run in a sequence.

I thought this has to do with these tags being created for the same commit, but I think that should not be the case for *annotated* tags.

Expected behavior:

```
git tag 1 -m v1; sleep 1; git tag 2 -m v2; sleep 1; git tag 3 -m v3
git describe --abbrev=0
3
```

Reproduce problem:

```
git tag 1 -m v1; git tag 2 -m v2; git tag 3 -m v3
git describe --abbrev=0
1
```

Comment: If they all reference the same commit, `1` is a completely valid description. When multiple descriptions are found, git will display [the first of them](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.6.3/builtin/describe.c#L381), based on the [order that they're found](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.6.3/builtin/describe.c#L168-L177).

Comment: That's what I gathered from other similar answers, but if you run the examples given in the description, one works and the other does not.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154485/git-describe-ignores-a-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["git describe" ignores a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154485/git-describe-ignores-a-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it was easier to enforce *one* annotated tag per commit.

First, retrieve the last annotated tag with `--abbrev=0`, check whether the current commit contains it and delete it if that's so.

```
last_version=$(git describe --abbrev=0)

if git tag --contains $(git rev-parse HEAD) | grep -q "^$last_version\$"; then
  git tag -d $last_version
fi

git tag $version -m $msg
```